# How to define type and value of variable in parameter of method in c#?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, return-value

Is it possible to **define type and value of variable in parameter of method** (existing types string, int, double or your own types)?

Reason for that is to define variable only at parameter not out of function, like other variable.

Example just for test:

```
public string test(string x){ return x; }

test(new StringBuilder{"New created string!!!"}[0].ToString()));
```

above will just return first char, we want to return hole string (or any other type).

If we try to use test method we will use it like this:

```
    1. example
string x = "some string";
test(x);

or 

2. example
test("some string");

could we make something to write variable inside parameter of method, something like

3. example (not valid)
test(new string("some string "));
```

point is that you put variable without previously define it like in 1 or 2 example

Comment: Do you mean [*generics*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)? Could you provide an example of what you have and what you **want** to have?

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean, but if you don't want just the first character, remove the `[0]` part...

Comment: @Sinatr well not generics, try to insert new variable in parameter x in test method without putting "", or defining variable previoslly.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you insert something like delegate inside x parameters in test method, ... without specifay variable before calling method, and without putting exact value, like "something"

Comment: This question has generics written all over it, why do you think that's not what you need?

Comment: Sorry, I *really* don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Take a bit of time to try to express yourself more clearly.

Comment: Do you mean *attributes*? Because you can assign them to parameters, I seen a code like `public string test([someattribute] string x)`, though I never need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can pass a "new" value into a function - you don't have to declare it outside of the function call.

I think your confusion comes from your incorrect syntax for creating a new `StringBuilder`:

```
test(new StringBuilder("New created string!!!")[0].ToString()));
```

or

```
test(new StringBuilder[]{new StringBuilder("New created string!!!")}[0].ToString()));
```

if your intent was to create an *array* of `StringBuilders` and then pass in the first one.

You can also use the *output* of another function directly in the call:

```
test(MethodThatReturnsAString());
```

Otherwise I have no idea what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the confusion seems to be that `System.String` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `System.String`. The following statement will not compile:

```
string x = new string("some string");
```

However, this will:

```
string x = "some string";
```

For all intents and purposes, the above two lines are the same.